# Predefined and custom items

Tags: database, database-design, entity, relational-database

I have the following piece of my DB:

```
project (id, name, color, ...)
unit (id, name, width, height, ...)
```

- each project consists of one or more units
- Each unit belongs to one project (1:N relationship with project)

And now comes the hard part:

There are predefined units saved which we can simply select (with fixed name/width/height):

- A predefined unit can be in several projects
- A project can have several predefined units (M:N relationship with projects)
- A predefined unit is a subtype of a unit (generalization)
- Remark: if a project already exists and has some default units, I don't want to change any values in the unit settings in case I edited the default properties of a default unit in future.

I am not able to find a suitable and working way to design the DB only because of the last part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have a Project_Unit table that allows many-to-many between the two. This can have attributes that default from Unit. The attributes on Unit itself can be conceptualized as being default values for the Project_unit attributes.

Comment: it is not that there are some default attributes and others are not. There are several whole units with default/predefined fixed values. Otherwise, you can create a customized unit and give the values you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a separate structure to hold predefined units, called `templates`.  With this approach a predefined units is assigned to a `project` by *copying* the data into `units`.

By all means have a flag or something on `units` which identifies it as *Predefined* and therefore cannot be altered.